# A question about finding a countable collection of open sets where intersection equal to S

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would one go about proving that the rationals are not the countable intersection of open sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61087/how-would-one-go-about-proving-that-the-rationals-are-not-the-countable-intersec)

As the topic, prove that set $S$ of rational numbers in the interval (0,1), cannot be expressed as the intersection of a countable collection of open sets.

Answer (score 3):

This follows immediately from the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem). Suppose that $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$, where each $U_n$ is open. For each $q\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ let $V_q=(0,1)\setminus\{q\}$. Then $$\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{V_q:q\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)\}$$ is a countable family of dense open subsets of $(0,1)$ whose intersection is empty. Since $(0,1)$ is locally compact, however, the Baire category theorem ensures that the intersection of a countable family of dense open sets is dense in $(0,1)$.