# Are the irrationals Gδ because they are uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, baire-category

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61110/1248511
I just saw this proof for showing that the rationals are not a Gδ set(without using baire's theorem) and while I'm not really sure about what exactly I'm asking, I wanted to know if there's any relation between the uncountability of the irrationals and the fact that they can be expressed as the intersection of open sets

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you talk about countability rather than commensurability. Yes, no countable dense set is $G_\delta$, but there are a lot of other subsets that also are not.

Comment: @mihalid Yes, thank you, I mixed up the terms. Does this mean that every uncountable, dense set is Gδ?

Comment: @NoetherBoy no, there are uncountable dense sets that are not even Borel (Bernstein sets for example)

Comment: @mihalid Ah i see. But there could never be a countable dense set Gδ, solely because of its countablity property?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Ah ok, does this mean that every countable dense set is not Gδ just because of it's countability alone?

Comment: @NoetherBoy the proof you linked works for any countable dense set. This doesn't say anything about uncounatble or non-dense sets - some of them are $G_\delta$, some are not.