# An example of a $F_{\sigma\delta}$ subset of $[0,1]$ of measure $1$ which is not $F_\sigma$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I'm trying to understand Borel sets. I am looking for a visual (i.e., constructive) $F_{\sigma\delta}$ subset of $[0,1]$ of measure $1$ which is not $F_\sigma$. Any idea or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$: it’s clearly a $G_\delta$ and therefore an $F_{\sigma\delta}$, but it’s [not an $F_\sigma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26311/proof-that-mathbbr-setminus-mathbbq-is-not-an-f-sigma-set).

Comment: @pin2: You’re welcome. (I don’t think that you can delete it now that there’s an upvoted answer.)

Comment: its ok. Thank you. +1

Comment: Didn't you mean in fact: "Not $G_{\delta\sigma}$?

Comment: @Etienne: No, I meant what I wrote.

Comment: In think, the question was for pin2...