# Subset of a $F_{\sigma}$ set is $F_{\sigma}$

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space. Is it always true that for any $F_{\sigma}$ set $A$, any subset $B \subset A$, $B$ is $F_{\sigma}$? It seems correct to me but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: $X$ itself is $F_{\sigma}$! So you are asking us if every subset is $F_{\sigma}$, which is not true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Observe that $\mathbb R$ is $F_\sigma$, but the subset $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ [is not.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26311/proof-that-mathbbr-setminus-mathbbq-is-not-an-f-sigma-set)