# Example of a unit circle subset that is $F_{\sigma\delta}$ but not $F_\sigma$

Tags: complex-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

I am looking for an example of a unit circle subset that is $F_{\sigma\delta}$ but not $F_\sigma$. The task is connected with studying convergence of power series on the boundary of the convergence set, so this is why being a subset of circle is needed.

Is $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}- \{z\in\mathbb{C}:z=e^{i\pi\phi}, \phi\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ a good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems right.  It's not $F_{\sigma}$ by the argument given in answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26311/proof-that-mathbbr-setminus-mathbbq-is-not-an-f-sigma-set) and it's $F_{\sigma\delta}$ because it equals $$\bigcap_{q\in \mathbf Q}S^1\setminus\{e^{i\pi q}\}$$

Comment: I am having a little trouble with formal proof and applying the same argument in that case, since using the complement of my set is not so easy - at least to me. Could you elaborate something more on this subject, please?

Comment: I'm uncertain what your difficulty is.  Why doesn't the proof translate almost word for word?  If $S^1\setminus\{e^{i\pi\phi}|\phi\in\mathbb Q\}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ then $\{e^{i\pi\phi}|\phi\in\mathbb Q\}$ is $G_{\delta}$ etc.